# Xamarin - How to display anything just on external display? android

Tags: android, xamarin

Is it possible to display one thing on the device's display and completely different on an external display? I need to be able to play 2 different videos on android device's display and an external monitor plugged in the HDMI port.

Currently I don't know how to even detect a second display or get it as a surface holder for example.

Comment: I don't think you can play two separate videos. External monitors just show what is on the device's screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found a book explaining exactly what I need. It is actually pretty simple...everything seems to be when you have the knowledge :).

So basically an external display is detected with the MediaRouter API and then a Presentation class is set to it. Here is link that explains everything:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.Presentation/